# C cross compile for raspberry pi with cmake fails to find header file

Tags: c, cmake, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling, libusb-1.0

I'm trying to port a program that runs fine in x86 architecture ([Linux Mint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint) 17.1) to a Raspberry Pi (Raspbian Jessie Lite). I'm using [CMake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMake), so I just followed the nice guide in [Crafty Bytes](http://amgaera.github.io/blog/2014/04/10/cross-compiling-for-raspberry-pi-on-64-bit-linux/).

My toolchain-raspberrypi.cmake looks like this:

```
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)

# Specify the cross compiler
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER $ENV{HOME}/rpi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc)

#SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-L$ENV{HOME}/rpi/rootfs/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I$ENV{HOME}$ENV{HOME}/rpi/rootfs/usr/include")

# Where is the target environment
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH $ENV{HOME}/rpi/rootfs)
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} --sysroot=${CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH}")
SET(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS} --sysroot=${CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH}")
SET(CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS} --sysroot=${CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH}")

# Search for programs only in the build host directories
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)

# Search for libraries and headers only in the target directories
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
```

CMake generates the Makefiles and seems to find all the required libraries:

```
$ cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -D CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/unknown/rpi/toolchain-raspberrypi.cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.3
-- Check for working C compiler: /home/unknown/rpi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /home/unknown/rpi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Looking for include file stdlib.h
-- Looking for include file stdlib.h - found
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for stddef.h
-- Looking for stddef.h - found
-- Check size of intmax_t
-- Check size of intmax_t - done
-- Check size of uintmax_t
-- Check size of uintmax_t - done
-- Check size of pid_t
-- Check size of pid_t - done
-- Found Lua51: /home/unknown/rpi/rootfs/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/liblua5.1.so;/home/unknown/rpi/rootfs/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so (found version "5.1.5")
-- Luaudio_INCLUDE_DIRS:     /home/unknown/rpi/rootfs/usr/include/lua5.1
-- LUA_LIBRARIES:         /home/unknown/rpi/rootfs/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/liblua5.1.so;/home/unknown/rpi/rootfs/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so
-- Found libusb-1.0:
--  - Includes: /home/unknown/rpi/rootfs/usr/include/libusb-1.0
--  - Libraries: /home/unknown/rpi/rootfs/usr/lib/libusb-1.0.a
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.26")
-- checking for one of the modules 'check'
-- Looking for include file pthread.h
-- Looking for include file pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE
-- Found libusb-1.0:
--  - Includes: /home/unknown/rpi/rootfs/usr/include/libusb-1.0
--  - Libraries: /home/unknown/rpi/rootfs/usr/lib/libusb-1.0.a
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/unknown/projects/ha/workspace/ha/build-rpi
```

But when I run make I get an error trying to locate a library header:

```
$ make
Scanning dependencies of target ha
[  2%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/ha.dir/log.c.o
[  5%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/ha.dir/cm.c.o
/home/unknown/projects/ha/workspace/ha/src/cm.c:13:31: fatal error: libusb-1.0/libusb.h: No such file or directory
 #include <libusb-1.0/libusb.h>
                               ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/ha.dir/cm.c.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/ha.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I'm totally stuck here. The files are there:

```
$ ls ~/rpi/rootfs/usr/include/libusb-1.0/ -l
total 72
-rw-r--r-- 1 unknown unknown 70156 jun 22  2014 libusb.h

$ ls ~/rpi/rootfs/usr/lib/libusb-1.0.a -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 unknown unknown 109920 jun 22  2014 /home/unknown/rpi/rootfs/usr/lib/libusb-1.0.a
```

And when running CMake with the `--trace` flag, it seems to find [libusb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libusb) related files:

```
/home/unknown/projectes/ha/workspace/ha/src/CMakeLists.txt(8):  find_package(libusb-1.0 REQUIRED )
/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/Findlibusb-1.0.cmake(46):  if(LIBUSB_1_LIBRARIES AND LIBUSB_1_INCLUDE_DIRS )
/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/Findlibusb-1.0.cmake(49):  else(LIBUSB_1_LIBRARIES AND LIBUSB_1_INCLUDE_DIRS )
/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/Findlibusb-1.0.cmake(50):  find_path(LIBUSB_1_INCLUDE_DIR NAMES libusb.h PATHS /usr/include /usr/local/include /opt/local/include /sw/include PATH_SUFFIXES libusb-1.0 )
/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/Findlibusb-1.0.cmake(62):  find_library(LIBUSB_1_LIBRARY NAMES usb-1.0 usb PATHS /usr/lib /usr/local/lib /opt/local/lib /sw/lib )
/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/Findlibusb-1.0.cmake(72):  set(LIBUSB_1_INCLUDE_DIRS ${LIBUSB_1_INCLUDE_DIR} )
/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/Findlibusb-1.0.cmake(75):  set(LIBUSB_1_LIBRARIES ${LIBUSB_1_LIBRARY} )
/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/Findlibusb-1.0.cmake(79):  if(LIBUSB_1_INCLUDE_DIRS AND LIBUSB_1_LIBRARIES )
/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/Findlibusb-1.0.cmake(80):  set(LIBUSB_1_FOUND TRUE )
/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/Findlibusb-1.0.cmake(83):  if(LIBUSB_1_FOUND )
/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/Findlibusb-1.0.cmake(84):  if(NOT libusb_1_FIND_QUIETLY )
/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/Findlibusb-1.0.cmake(85):  message(STATUS Found libusb-1.0: )
-- Found libusb-1.0:
/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/Findlibusb-1.0.cmake(86):  message(STATUS  - Includes: ${LIBUSB_1_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
--  - Includes: /home/unknown/rpi/rootfs/usr/include/libusb-1.0
/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/Findlibusb-1.0.cmake(87):  message(STATUS  - Libraries: ${LIBUSB_1_LIBRARIES} )
--  - Libraries: /home/unknown/rpi/rootfs/usr/lib/libusb-1.0.a
/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/Findlibusb-1.0.cmake(96):  mark_as_advanced(LIBUSB_1_INCLUDE_DIRS LIBUSB_1_LIBRARIES )
/home/unknown/projectes/ha/workspace/ha/src/CMakeLists.txt(10):  INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${LIBUSB_1_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
```

I'm a newcomer to CMake and so far I've not been able to find any helpful entry in this site nor anywhere else regarding this same problem.

Any clue?

Comment: `apt-get install libusb1.0-dev`. Looking into output closer, the auto tools are using `pkg-config` to determine path of the header. Your system has no development library installed. The rest is your home work.

Comment: @0andriy libusb1.0-dev is already installed (both in the host and the faked rootfs). Sorry, I thought it was clear from the fact that both libusb1.0a and libusb1.0/libusb.h are there.

Comment: You comment adjusting `CMAKE_CFLAGS` for search headers under `/home/unknown/rpi/rootfs/usr/include`. So compiler doesn't search there. Also, as `/home/unknown/rpi/rootfs/` is actually a sysroot (isn't it?), tell that to CMake **directly**: `set(CMAKE_SYSROOT "/home/unknown/rpi/rootfs/")`. With that CMake will automatically add appropriate options for compiler and linker, and will automatically treat this path as *CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH*.

Comment: Thanks @tsyvarev. The line is commented out because it was one of the things I tried to make it work, but it makes no difference. I just tried the `CMAKE_SYSROOT` suggestion and unfortunately it makes no difference either... :(

Comment: See what's passed to the compiler with `make VERBOSE=1`.

Comment: That could be a problem: message `- Includes: /home/unknown/rpi/rootfs/usr/include/libusb-1.0` for *libusb* means that header is **expected** to be included as `#include <libusb.h>`. And this path should be added into header's search path. But error message tells, that the header is **actually** included as `#include <libusb-1.0/libusb.h>`. As workaround you may try to edit CMake cache and replace path `/home/unknown/rpi/rootfs/usr/include/libusb-1.0` with `/home/unknown/rpi/rootfs/usr/include`. You need to reconfigure the project (run `cmake`) after that modification.

Comment: Thanks @Tsyvarev, yes, I didn't realize that! I'm wondering why find_package works differently when cross compiling. I did a _dirty_ workaround, as I need to both build the project for the PC and the Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem

From the `cmake --trace` output one can see, that `Findlibusb-1.0.cmake` script, which search *libusb-1.0* library, detects include directory for the library's headers via

```
find_path(LIBUSB_1_INCLUDE_DIR NAMES libusb.h ...)
```

This means, that the script **expects** `libusb.h` header to be included as

```
#include <libusb.h>
```

(The same conclusion can be deduced from the output of `cmake` call: line

```
- Includes: /home/unknown/rpi/rootfs/usr/include/libusb-1.0
```

already includes `libusb-1.0` suffix for the include path.)

But error message shows, that `cm.c` file **actually includes** the header as

```
#include <libusb-1.0/libusb.h>
```

This means, that `Findlibusb-1.0.cmake` script you use (which is shipped with CMake itself) **is not compatible** with actual usage of the library in you project.

### Ideal solution

You need to ship your project with *compatible* `Findlibusb-1.0.cmake` script, which uses

```
find_path(LIBUSB_1_INCLUDE_DIR NAMES libusb-1.0/libusb.h ...)
```

for detect include path. E.g., the [one](https://github.com/otherlab/pcl/blob/master/cmake/Modules/Findlibusb-1.0.cmake) from PCL library. (At the beginning of your project's `CMakeLists.txt` you need to adjust `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` variable for find the script.)

### As fast workaround

You may replace path `/home/unknown/rpi/rootfs/usr/include/libusb-1.0` with `/home/unknown/rpi/rootfs/usr/include` in the CMake cache. (After modification of the cache you need to rerun `cmake`).

Because cached value is likely used in `include_directories()` call from your project, proper directory will be used instead.

---

> I'm wondering why find_package works differently when cross compiling.

More likely that `find_package` works identical on PC and when cross-compiling, but on PC you get path `/usr/include` being included by other means (e.g., it is included by default).